# Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression for deep nested object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a reactjs project in which there is a useState variable which is very nested. Something like this:

```
{
    
    chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 430
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: false,
      dataLabels: {
        position: 'top',
      },
    }
  },
    colors,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    offsetX: -6,
    style: {
      fontSize: '12px',
      colors: ['#fff']
    }
  },
  stroke: {
    show: true,
    width: 1,
    colors: ['#fff']
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    intersect: false
  },
  
  xaxis: {
    categories: ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thru","Fri","Sat","Sun"],
  },
  }
```

I want to change the value of `categories` in `xaxis`. Here's how I am doing it:

```
 if(days[index]==="Daily"){
      let temp = {...options};
      temp?.xaxis?.categories = chartData?.days?.days;
      setData(chartData?.days);
      setOptions(temp);
    }
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression. (72:6)

  70 |     if(days[index]==="Daily"){
  71 |       let temp = {...options};
> 72 |       temp?.xaxis?.categories = chartData?.days?.days;
     |       ^
  73 |       setData(chartData?.days);
  74 |       setOptions(temp);
  75 |     }
```

May anyone knows what I am doing wrong ? or I can't modify the value of deep object like this?

Comment: `temp?.xaxis?.categories` could be undefined and you cannot assign a value to undefined.

Comment: `temp?.` is pointless, since it's always an object.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `.xaxis` doesn't exist? Should it not assign anything? Should it create the object?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(temp?.xaxis){
  temp.xaxis.categories = chartData?.days?.days;
}
```